# Spacing in maths mode between stackrel and mathrel

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I would like to obtain consistent spacing of symbols obtained with a `\stackrel` when they are next to a `\mathrel` operator such as the colon (`:`).
Out of the box, the `\stackrel` symbols have their spacing relative to operators reduced.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{ll}
Hc
\\
H\stackrel{\triangledown}{c} &\text{ spacing increased}
\\
-
\\
H:c
\\
H:\stackrel{\triangledown}{c} &\text{ spacing reduced!}
\\
H\mathbin{:}\stackrel{\triangledown}{c} &\text{ with mathbin}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Turing the colon into a mathbin isn't any better, as spacing is not symmetric either.

Alternatively, if there's a better way (including for vertical positioning) than `\stackrel` to produce these symbols, this is welcome.

Comment: You don't want `\stackrel`, but rather `\overset`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `\overset` rather than `\stackrel` (the latter always makes a relation symbol).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%%%%%%%\everymath{\displaystyle}%%%% DON'T!!!!

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{l}
Hc\\
H\overset{\triangledown}{c}
\\
H:c
\\
H:\overset{\triangledown}{c}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, `accents` does a better job.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{accents}

%%%%%%%\everymath{\displaystyle}%%%% DON'T!!!!

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{l}
Hc\\
H\accentset{\triangledown}{c}
\\
H:c
\\
H:\accentset{\triangledown}{c}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

***Don't*** do `\everymath{\displaystyle}`.

Comment: Thanks for this. `accents` is interesting, but I run into problems when I use it within comments I produce with `todonotes` or even within figure captions: is there a way to make it robust wrt such inclusions?

Comment: @Joce Add `\NewDocumentCommand{\trdown}{m}{\accentset{\triangledown}{#1}}` to your preamble and use `\trdown{c}` in the document (choose a name you like for the command).